# Regex that should match 0-999, 0.0-999.9 as well as 0,0-999,9

Tags: regex, typescript

I am once again struggling with regex. I need a regex which matches only numbers from 0-999 or numbers from 0-999 with one decimal, eg. 0.0-999.9.

The Regex I made `/^([1-9][0-9]{0,2})|([1-9][0-9]{0,2})[,.][0-9]$/` has the error that it matches also 1. instead of 1.5, that shouldn't be the case.

Further examples:

```
1 -> Match (in range 0-999)
1. -> No Match (no decimal)
1, -> Again no Match (no decimal)
1,5 -> Matches (in range 0,0-999,9)
1324 -> does not Match (over 999,9)
15.5 -> Matches (in range 0.0-999.9)
999,9 -> Matches (max. reached)
```

Thanks in advance for your Help.

Comment: Edge cases, is `01` valid?  Is `1.0` valid? Is `0` valid?  Is `.1` valid? Is `0001` valid?

Comment: What about a two step approach? Get the number, then check if it's valid?

Comment: Hello again, @RobertMcKee the usage would be for school exams, concretely for their points. Therefore the Regex should match Points from 0-999 but they should also be entered as decimal, separated by a . (dot) as well as a , (comma). Therefore is 01 not valid, 1.0 is valid, 0 is also valid (it is possible that you retrieve an exam with zero points), .1 is not valid and 0001 is also not valid.

Comment: Hello @MadPhysicist, Yes that would be an option too. Give me an example and then we will look which solutions are better for this type of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match from 0 - 999 with an optional part to match either a `.` or a `,`, you could use

```
^\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d)?$
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bYFgzo/1)

Answer (score 1):

`^(?:[1-9]\d{1,2}|\d)(?:[.,]\d)?$` should work.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vsL89V/3

Comment: Is this supposed to match `0` or `0.0`?

Comment: @jcalz It does now.  Still waiting on his response to the other edge cases though.